# Zeitgeist and vim/gvim

Tags: vim, gnome, gvim

If I open file via nautilus and edit it in gvim Zeitgeist shows an
entry for this file. Doing the same but opening the file from bash/zsh
with vim/gvim Zeitgeist shows no entry for this action.

Is it possible and what is to do that both actions behave same?

edit:
[Some screenshots on Zeitgeist / Gnome Activity Journal](http://seilo.geekyogre.com/2010/01/gnome-activity-journal-looking-sexy/)

Comment: could you linke to whatever "zeitgeist" is? just for the people who have no clue about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, [Zeigeist](http://live.gnome.org/Zeitgeist) is a [*Gnome* activity journal](https://launchpad.net/gnome-activity-journal). It records what you do in Nautilus because that's a Gnome application. It won't notice anything if you start vim from bash or zsh. I'm not sure about opening a file in GVim.

You might wish to make a feature request to the Zeitgeist developers to provide command line access, e.g. so you can run `zeitgeist-record vim foo` to record that you ran `vim` on `foo`. (Or document the feature if it already exists.)

Comment: Zeitgeist is not a gnome activity journal. Gnome activity journal uses zeitgeist to display all the events that zeitgeist has recorded.

Comment: @Dolanor ... which would make Zeitgeist an activity journal that is used by Gnome, no? (And Gnome Activity Journal the application to view the journal.) Or does it (out of the box) log things that happen outside of Gnome as well? Is there something like `zeigeist-record` now (I didn't find anything three years ago)?

Comment: No but there are projects to feed zeitgeist with their own data like [zeitgeist-datasources](https://launchpad.net/zeitgeist-datasources). The project seems to have moved from launchpad for code, but launchpad is still used for other things. (and I get a lot of gateway timeout on the official website)

Answer (score 4):

You can get this by installing `zeitgeist-datasource-vim`  from this PPA

https://launchpad.net/~zeitgeist/+archive/ppa

Additionally you can install it from source (if you want). Instructions here

http://wiki.zeitgeist-project.com/Installing_Zeitgeist_Dataproviders_from_trunk